# Cannot use System.IO.Compression and SQLite both referenced in a WP8.1 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, base-class-library, sqlite.net

I have a strange error in my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project. I just created a small test project and get the same behaviour:

If I install
"Microsoft.Bcl.Compression"

and then
"SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8"

via NuGet I get the following exception if I try to compress a file even if I am not using SQLite.NET at all in any line.

In the following code at entry.Open():

```
var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(file.Name));

using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
```

> An exception of type 'System.IO.Compression.ZLibException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The underlying compression routine could not
>   be loaded correctly.

If I remove SQLite from the project then the compression runs successfully as expected.

I used the compression some months without problems and then added SQLite.NET support and now ended up in a strange exception.

Do I do something wrong?

Small test project:
[CompressionAndSQLiteExample.zip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F84FF9BBE37AB03F!322&authkey=!ALsRV8emh_xx4QE&ithint=file%2Czip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the Microsoft.Bcl.Compression.targets script in that it uses the same target name as sqlite-net-wp8, InjectReference.

I changed InjectReference to BCLCompressionInjectReference and reloaded the project and now it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really solved my problem! I just did the changes you described in the file "\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Compression.3.9.85\build\wp8\Microsoft.Bcl.Compression.targets" an voilà :)

Comment: It looks like most of the SQLite packages have changed their Target naming to avoid this, but sqlite-net-wp8 still has the issue in 3.8.5. It's addressed in their repo, but not released yet in nuget: https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8/commit/bed0b15ba687e2b3c00bbdb19074cfce5e56910f